# Why self praise is considered equal to suicide?

Tags: mahabharata

From Mahabharata incident, explained in the comments [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17769/8696). Actually, I'm not accepting those comments as  authority but accepting as I had read the incident in Mahabharata in the past. Question In other words Why one shouldn't praise oneself?

Comment: Which Mahabharata incident are you referring?..

Comment: There was a story of a king who reached heaven due to his punya. When he reached there, out of enthusiasm, he asked people there,  "Did other people here also reach heaven by doing good deeds just like me?" Then Indra interferes and said "Do you think you have done good deeds and doing self-praise that u have done punya? Getout of heaven." To reach again here, prove yourself that you have done good deeds (without coming from your mouth). [1/2]

Comment: They descend to earth. Then tortoise in a lake in his kingdom answers when asked by Indra whether he has done any punya. It says "The king  done numerous godanas. When those thousands of cows walked, due to force of their legs, a lake was formed and I am living in that lake." Knowing the punya, indra allows the king back to heaven. This incident signifies that self-praise(atma stuti) and ill-speaking of others(para ninda) is condemned.  2/2

Comment: You can read [reference](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08069.htm) of that incident which I mentioned in that comment. Continue onto next page as well

Comment: To answer your question - Boasting is a shameful deed, and since great men think it is better to die than to live in shame, boasting is considered suicide.

Comment: Anytime you inform others of your good deeds, the punya of that good deed gets destroyed. Anytime you inform others of your bad deeds, the papa of that bad deed gets destroyed. People love to boast their good deeds and are ashamed to declare their bad deeds.